# GNU Debugger (GDB) and "help info leaks"?

Tags: c, gdb

I am running GDB 7.2 on Linux 64 bit machine. It all works fine but now I want to try use GDB to help me detect memory leaks as shown in the following article:

http://geocities.ws/murugesan/technical/gdb/memoryleak_gdb.html

There is a section that says:

```
GDB with info leaks command availability check:

      # gdb -q
      (gdb) help info leaks  
      If you find the help for that command,then GDB is capable to debug the program for memory leaks.  Else the support of GDB to find the memory leaks is not available in that GDB version.
```

When I do "help info leaks" I get nothing ;-(

Do I have to do it for a specific compiled file? Something like "file myprog", and then do everything?

BTW: How do you guys find using GDB for finding memory leaks?

Comment: The result you get means your installed version of GDB does not support that feature.

For memory leaks detection, I am using http://valgrind.org/, and I found it very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my only issue with Valgrind is can I use it on Solaris as well? I wonder why the latest version of GDB does not support leak detection, perhaps I have to compile from source and pass in some compile options? Thanks again ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title of that page is: "MEMORY LEAK DETECTION  on *HP-UNIX* PLATFORMS".

The "info leaks" was added as HP-UX extension to GDB, and never made it into FSF release of GDB (which most Linux distributions use).

On Linux, just use Valgrind.

On Solaris, use [libumem](http://blogs.oracle.com/pnayak/entry/finding_memory_leaks_within_solaris).